# flow type, bounded generics for anonymous function

Tags: generics, flowtype

Well this seems like either something is obviously missing from flow or I don't understand it. But how could one put bounds on a generic, when using an (anonymous) arrow function?

```
// @flow

const fun = async <T> (val: T, x: number) => {};

const foo = async <T: number> (val: T, x: number) => {
}
```

Shows the error

```
5: const foo = async <T: number> (val: T, x: number) => {
                       ^ Unexpected token `:`, expected the start of a statement
```

see: https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiDGsB2BnALqSBXdUAXlAENMBPdFUAHgBUA+UACgDczoAuUBgGlAAPXunwBbAEYBTAE4BKEiwDeAXwDcyNFlyRYsEuSo16DURJmyWHLrwHDzUuYuIrEqoA

Comment: I tried the code on different versions of Flow and it seems to work on v0.50.0 and break on v0.51.0. I haven't figured out what commit broke the behavior. The workaround is to define a generic function type and just set `const fun: CustomFunctionType = ...`.

Comment: Looks like it's a recurring issue on GitHub, e.g., https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/5335.